# Lucene - Unable to import EnglishAnalyzer

Tags: java, lucene

I am quite new to Lucene, and I am currently working on indexing a collection of files using Lucene 8.2.0, writing my code in the Eclipse IDE.

I did include the `lucene-core-8.2.0.jar` library in my Eclipse project (as an external JAR), and so far I've been able to use Lucene classes like `StandardAnalyzer` and `IndexWriter`, except for this one, for which I am getting:

```
EnglishAnalyzer cannot be resolved to a type
```

Organizing imports in Eclipse did not help, and neither did this:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer;
```

For this last statement, it seems that `org.apache.lucene.analysis.en` cannot be resolved:

```
The import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en cannot be resolved
```

Any clue about what I am doing wrong would be really appreciated.

*Side note:* I want to use `EnglishAnalyzer` because I need an analyzer that removes stopwords and performs stemming on the input documents. If there are any other Lucene Analyzers I should be using instead, please let me know.

Comment: I guess the library is not on the buildpath. I recommend to use a build tool like Gradle to manage dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `EnglishAnalyzer` class is located in the analyzers-common JAR file, and not in the core JAR file, so I included it in my project and now all is fine. The JAR name for version 8.2.0 is:

```
lucene-analyzers-common-8.2.0.jar
```